# Is there a way to push/pop a bookmark while reading an xml file?

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader

I am reading a large XML file (a Triangulated Irregular Network in LandXML format).  Currently I read it in fine and it gives correct elevation values (or slope -- whatever I would like).  I want to explore ways to read it differently.  [Note: The purpose of this is to optimize other operations later in the process by changing from a Dictionary to a ptsDTMpoint Array, so I need to know the point count before allocating the array.]

The following code currently works:

```
// in scope as class members:
private Dictionary<ulong, ptsDTMpoint> allPoints;

// critical portion of currently sound method:
reader.ReadToDescendant("Pnts");
reader.Read();               // Would like to set a bookmark here
                             // or suspend reading here so I can
                             // Ulong numberOfPoints = countPoints(reader);
while (!(reader.Name.Equals("Pnts") && reader.NodeType.Equals(XmlNodeType.EndElement)))
{
   UInt64 id;
   if (reader.NodeType.Equals(XmlNodeType.Element))
   {
      UInt64.TryParse(reader.GetAttribute("id"), out id);
      reader.Read();
      if (reader.NodeType.Equals(XmlNodeType.Text))
      {
         scratchPoint = new ptsDTMpoint(reader.Value, id);
         if (allPoints == null)
         {                                                    // next line will change (later) to 
            allPoints = new Dictionary<ulong, ptsDTMpoint>(); // = new ptsDTMpoint[numberOfPoints]();
            myBoundingBox = new ptsBoundingBox2d(scratchPoint);
         }
         allPoints.Add(id, scratchPoint);    // also would change to allPoints[counter] = scratchPoint;
         myBoundingBox.expandByPoint(scratchPoint);
      }
   }
   reader.Read();
}
```

Comment: Why an array? Why not go with a `List<ptsDTMpoint>`? That would save you from having to know the number of points in advance. If you had some estimate you could even size the list reasonably close initially to save time in growing it. Another alternative would be to simply convert the `Dictionary` into an array when you're done.

Comment: There is no particular reason to have an Array over a List<>, so I will go with that.  Regarding your second suggestion, convert the Dictionary, I no longer need the collection in the form of Dictionary, so I want to avoid any space or time penalties that approach would incur.

Comment: Okay, so I have a lot of investigation to do before I am sure this will work, and I do this during my hobby time (I am not at work.)  Thus I have to continue changing my implementation and verify that it works 24 hours from now or so.  In other words, I may have a "particular reason" after all, but I have to do a lot before I can be sure.

Comment: `List<T>` supports the semantics of an array, i.e., look up by index, but is dynamically sized. Internally it uses an array for storage and grows it as needed. You can make it more efficient by using the constructor that takes an integer size to create the internal storage large enough to hold your expected collection to avoid the growth penalty.  It's a good choice if you are going to iterating over them, but less good if you need to look up by key.

Comment: I do a lot of lookup by key because the points are not guaranteed to be sorted when imported.*  But since array lookup is O(1), and since List<> is implemented as Array, isn't List lookup by key (that is, by index) also O(1)?   (*And if they are, they are only sorted in x, not y.)

Comment: If your key is an integer, it's possible that you could use an array or a list and insert each item at it's appropriate place - but that could leave you with a very sparse list and, perhaps, an impossibly large amount of memory required. I suspect, based on your description, that you probably still want to use a `Dictionary` unless your keys are sequential and you expect to fill all elements of the array you allocate.